# Can't focus with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to focus on input when the search icon is clicked so the user can start typing without having to click on the input manually. Ideally, it should be something like this, but focus() doesn't work on this input for some reason.

```
$('.header__icons a[role="button"]').click(function(){
     $('#q').focus();
})
```

I've tried various options, but nothing..I see this input gets "focus-visible" and "data-focus-visible-added" when clicked on. I tried adding them manually, but it doesn't focus it either. I also couldn't locate any functions related to this in the files.

**EDIT:** The code works fine, just added setTimeout..and dev console was the reason I wasn't seeing any changes here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the code you have should work. I recommend you close the browser's developer console and test it again.
The reason it probably doesn't work is that focus() doesn't steal focus from the dev console.

Try using a setTimeout in the dev console and then quickly click in your browser window, then you should see it focus the search box.

```
setTimeout(function() { $('input[name="q"]').focus() }, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the dev console! I thought I was crazy already haha

Comment: 3000 is very high, people can start typing and it goes nowhere. In the real code use 0 instead. All you need is to wait for the next tick so the other click handler can execute.

Comment: @CherryDT thanks, I used 500, worked good for me :)

Comment: I recommend 0 anyway, because I think from a UX perspective it's unexpected that you _can_ type but _only_ after some arbitrary delay.

Comment: @CherryDT the issue here is (at least, appears to be) that OP has focus in the console, so needs time to click into the main window after entering the `.focus()` code (in the console)   The `$("a").click..` code *should* be unaffected and not need a setTimeout.

Comment: @freedomn-m I thought it was because the element is display:none at that point (looked like it on the page they linked), so it does need setTimeout, but when they tried it in the console (without click handler, just the focus setting, in an attempt to debug the problem) it didn't work either because this time the console was focused.

Comment: @CherryDT that might explain some of the other answers that mention "after the animation".  There's currently no link in the question.  Looking at the history, and using the link there, it works fine.  Which is, of course, why all code should be in the question.  If it was caused by an animation, OP should hook into the animation callback, using `setTimeout` (even with 0) should never be the correct answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m In theory and an ideal world, that's correct, however this is simply not how most "everyday website development" works nowadays. (Which is why I don't develop websites unless someone really begs me to, and then it will be done "right" and be quite expensive, but I digress.) In this case it's likely functionality provided by some Shopify template or plugin and the OP would like to improve the UX by adding JS that handles the focus. In these cases, any solution that assumes total control over (and/or understanding of) what's rendered or executed on the site is often not very helpful.

Comment: See their [app.js](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0285/8103/6125/t/123/assets/app.js?v=2045539142757494321) which is the custom JavaScript that is used to augment the existing template. (They already added the `setTimeout` there by now.) Note it _doesn't_ initiate the animation, so there is no easy way to hook into it. Also, it wouldn't have to wait for it to complete entirely, only to reach the next tick at which `display:none` is removed (`opacity` is fine). For the same reason electricians sometimes "abuse" unused ground wires as switch wires, because they have to work with what's there.

Answer (score 0):

use setTimeout to wait animation complete

```js
$('.header__icons a[role="button"]').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#q').focus();
  }, 1000)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. The problem I wasn't seeing any focus was the dev console

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when the user clicks the button, the field is not yet visible, so it cannot be focused. It will be visible in the next tick though (doesn't matter that it's transparent - it's about whether it's rendered at all or not), so you can use `setTimeout` with a timeout of zero:

```js
$('.header__icons a[role="button"]').click(function(){
     setTimeout(() => $('#q').focus(), 0)
})
```